# How to access object during by deciding the object during runtime?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to Typescript. I am looking to access the object in my Typescript code. In my code, the target object will be decided at runtime based on the argument.

```
const obj123 = {
   id: 12,
   colour: 'blue'
 }

const obj111 = {
   id: 15,
   colour: 'black'
 }

class test {
  getValue(objId: string) {
   // need to access either obj123 or obj111 based on the value of 'objId' here 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Put them in an array and use `.find()` to get the one that matches `objId`

Comment: @Andreas there will be more objects added. We can't maintain them manually in an array.

Comment: Unless you add them all as global objects to `window` you have to somehow "maintain" them in a collection you can work with.